# Pure virtual method called

Tags: c++, methods, pure-virtual

I understand why calling a virtual function from a constructor is bad, but I'm not sure why defining a destructor would result in a "pure virtual method called" exception.  The code uses const values to reduce the use of dynamic allocation - possibly also the culprit.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class ActionBase {
 public:
    ~ActionBase() { } // Comment out and works as expected

    virtual void invoke() const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Action : public ActionBase {
 public:
    Action( T& target, void (T::*action)())
     : _target( target ), _action( action ) { }

    virtual void invoke() const {
        if (_action) (_target.*_action)();
    }

    T&   _target;
    void (T::*_action)();
};

class View {
 public:
    void foo() { cout << "here" << endl; }
};

class Button : public View {
 public:
    Button( const ActionBase& action )
     : _action( action ) { }

    virtual void mouseDown() {
        _action.invoke();
    }

 private:
    const ActionBase& _action;
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    View view;
    Button button = Button( Action<View>( view, &View::foo ) );
    button.mouseDown();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should make `ActionBase`'s destructor `virtual`. See http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-functions.html#faq-20.7

Comment: Add a destructor to Action<> that prints out when it is destroyed and you will see it dying before it can be used and thus invoking undefined behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You have Undefined Behavior.**  As the parameter to Button's ctor is a const& from a temporary, it is destroyed at the end of that line, right after the ctor finishes.  You later use _action, after Action's dtor has already run.  Since this is UB, **the implementation is allowed to let anything happen**, and apparently your implementation happens to do something slightly different depending on whether you have a trivial dtor in ActionBase or not.  You get the "pure virtual called" message because the implementation is providing behavior for calling ActionBase::invoke directly, which is what happens when the implementation changes the object's vtable pointer in Action's dtor.

I recommend using **[boost.function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/function.html)** or a similar 'action callback' library (boost has [signals](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals.html) and [signals2](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/signals2.html), for example).

Comment: About undefined-ness... I checked the assembly, it seems that gcc didn't destroy `Action` hierarchy *at all*, if destructor was "trivial"--i.e. compiler-generated.  So the code correctly caught vtable pointer without destructor since it remained in memory unoverwritten.

Comment: There's no correctly catching this; it's undefined behavior and all bets are off *in the entire program* (as far as the standard guarantees).  What you found does make sense though, in the trivial-dtor case the vtable pointer isn't updated, so no error message.

Comment: Demons flying from the nose and all that.

Comment: Thanks Roger, now I understand what's going on.  I only recently started using const for non-trivial code, so the scope of action wasn't entirely clear to me.

Answer (score 3):

Set a breakpoint on the destructor and it will become clear what is happening.  Yup, you are passing a temporary instance of Action<> to the Button constructor.  It is destroyed after the button construct runs.  Write it like this and the problem disappears:

```
View view;
Action<View> event(view, &View::foo);
Button button = Button( event ); 
button.mouseDown();
```

Well, that's not a practical solution, event is not going to be in scope for a real mouseDown invocation.  The Button constructor is going to have to create a copy of the "event" argument or it is going to have to manage a pointer to the delegate.

Comment: +1. But why 'Action<View> event = Action<View>(view,&view::foo)'? Why not 'Action<View>  event(view,&View::foo)';

Answer (score 2):

A class with virtual functions should always have a virtual destructor, so `~ActionBase()` should be virtual, (and so should `~Action()`). If you turn on more compiler warning you will get a warning about this.

Essentially, because of the lookup rules, the destructor is called for a type that the compiler **knows** cannot be instantiated (pure virtual), so it knows something must have gone wrong.

I'm sure someone else can explain better than I can :)

Comment: While you're very right in your advice, that doesn't have anything to do with the problem in subject.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer guys.  With a virtual destructor, this still compiles and executes with a "pure virtual method called" error with gcc-ubuntu-64 4.3.3.

The first produces the error, the next does not.  What is inherently different between the two?  The second takes the address of a temporary, which of course is not good.  Does the first also?

Button button = Button( Action<View>( view, &View::foo ) );

Action<View> action( view, &View::foo );
Button button2 = Button( action );

Comment: Mike: The issue isn't taking the taking the address of a temporary, but using a reference after the lifetime has ended for the object to which it refers (see my answer).